# TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: conda, apple-m1, arm64, apple-silicon

Device: Macbook M1 Pro(arm64)
Note:I am using zsh. I looked through previously provided solution to the related problem but still got the same error.
I tried to use installer from miniconda pkg installer for apple silicion M1 64 bit and still got the same error.

I first installed miniforge with

> > homebrew install --cask miniforge
> > I then tired to initialize it.
> > I first tiried,
> > conda init -dvv zsh
> > and,
> > conda init -vv zsh
> > and got the same old error.

```
lucifer@Manojs-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda init -vv zsh
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(236): verbosity set to 2
DEBUG conda.gateways.subprocess:subprocess_call(78): executing>> /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python --version


/Users/lucifer/.zshrc
--- 

+++ 

@@ -1,2 +1,18 @@

 
 echo "alias blender=/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/MacOS/blender"
+
+# >>> conda initialize >>>
+# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
+__conda_setup="$('/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
+if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
+    eval "$__conda_setup"
+else
+    if [ -f "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
+        . "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
+    else
+        export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin:$PATH"
+    fi
+fi
+unset __conda_setup
+# <<< conda initialize <<<
+
INFO conda.core.initialize:run_plan(640): init_sh_user: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 638, in run_plan
    result = globals()[step['function']](*step.get('args', ()), **step.get('kwargs', {}))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 1331, in init_sh_user
    with open(user_rc_path, 'w') as fh:
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/common/compat.py", line 69, in open
    return io_open(file, str(mode), buffering=buffering,
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/lucifer/.zshrc'
DEBUG conda.gateways.subprocess:subprocess_call(78): executing>> sudo /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/bin/python -m conda.core.initialize
Password:DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(236): verbosity set to 2

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1129, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 86, in main_subshell
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 93, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/cli/main_init.py", line 50, in execute
        return initialize(context.conda_prefix, selected_shells, for_user, args.system,
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 119, in initialize
        run_plan_elevated(plan2)
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/core/initialize.py", line 688, in run_plan_elevated
        result = subprocess_call(
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda/gateways/subprocess.py", line 100, in subprocess_call
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=stdin)
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1152, in communicate
        stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
      File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1983, in _communicate
        input_view = memoryview(self._input)
    TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

`$ /opt/homebrew/bin/conda init -vv zsh`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 INFOPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/info:
                  MANPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/man::
                     PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr
                          /sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
       user config file : /Users/lucifer/.condarc
 populated config files : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/.condarc
          conda version : 22.9.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=11.6=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=arm64
       base environment : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/pkgs
                          /Users/lucifer/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs
                          /Users/lucifer/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/22.9.0 requests/2.28.1 CPython/3.10.6 Darwin/20.6.0 OSX/11.6
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers? [y/N]: DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(236): verbosity set to 2

No report sent. To permanently opt-out, use

    $ conda config --set report_errors false
```

Comment: Can you share the `~/.zshrc` file? Seems like it is dying while trying to execute the initialize transaction. Or try running with extra verbosity, e.g., first with a dry-run, `conda init -dvv zsh`, then attempt again `conda init -vv zsh`.

Comment: I did tried with the above mentioned commands and still the same error.

Comment: That’s not just the same error. It now also shows permission issue with the .zshrc file. Please check the permission on the file (`ls -l`) - you may need to add write permission to the file.

Comment: does that mean, I need to give written permission to users or all ?

Comment: No - that would be a major security vulnerability. Just need to make sure the user executing the `conda init` has write permissions. Presumably, that should be `lucifer`. Maybe share the output of `ls -l /Users/lucifer/.zshrc` in the question body if you need further help.

Comment: I tried as per the suggestion to let the user have to write permission to the .zshrc file and finish the installation. It was installed without error. Once installed, I removed the write permission from the user.

Comment: An individual user should normally have write permissions to their own `.zshrc`